# How are these structures called in American and British English?

Tags: american-english, nouns, british-english

[image]

What do you call this **little building** in which a guard sits and lets people in and out of a company's premises and what is the name of that **horizontal bar** which he raises from inside of the building(unless ofc when it's manually operated)?

is the bar the same as:

**A boom barrier**, also known as a boom gate, is a bar, or pole pivoted to allow the boom to block vehicular or pedestrian access through a controlled point(Wikipedia:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boom_barrier)

**?**

As to definitions for the building, I only found these synonyms in a Polish-English dictionary Ling.pl

-watchman's lodge

-GATE-HOUSE

-LODGE

-**guard-room**

When I googled these none of them matched the description although the guard room came close.

: a room occupied by a military guard during its term of duty (Merriam Webster)

: a room where military prisoners are confined (Merriam Webster)

The problem with these definitions is that they say "**military guard**" does this term extend to all guards in such a building?

Comment: In the UK, I'd call this a security booth, regardless of whether there is a physical barrier or not.  I don't know what Americans would call it. Sorry. I'm not American.

Comment: In the British military, a building where military prisoners are confined (and the military police are based) is called a guardroom (one word). They don't look like the picture.

Comment: I pass a more elaborate/secure version of one of these quite frequently. No-one ever refers to the building by name, only by 'function' Coming/going through 'security', passing through the gate [even though it's a lifting barrier] "I spoke to Bob at security this morning", "Check in at security on your way in". Never any mention of a named place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In US English, I would probably call it a *guard house*, *guard hut*, or *guard shack*.

*Room* does not work because a room is part of a larger building that is divided into multiple rooms.

I would call the barrier simply a *gate* or a *barrier*.  I've never heard the term "boom barrier", and it sounds like a specialist's technical term for it.

Answer (score 1):

In British usage, such a small building is often called a 'kiosk', and they can be used for various purposes, often signified by a preceding word, such as 'security', 'entrance', 'retail', 'grocery', 'ticket', 'food', etc.

A movable bar across an entrance or exit to a building, car park, etc, is often called a 'barrier'.

[image]

[image]